# Multiple Part Http Post Request C#

Tags: c#, web-services, post, webclient

I'll try to explain this as best as possible, I'm new to webservices/requests in C#.

Using WebClient, I've created a request with multiple header values. Along with these values, an image (.dat) file has to be sent along with the request. I am unable to do so. For a better idea here is my code:

```
 Console.WriteLine("Beginning SendRequest!");
        string img = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"\\[SERVER NAME]\mages\Images\" + imgNum + ".dat");
        ChequeData imgdata = new Data();
        helpers help = new helpers();
        imgdata = help.getData(data);

        WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
        myWebClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
        myWebClient.Headers.Add("PTC_TIMESTAMP", date);
        // there are 10 more Headers.Add() which hold private information

        // add the image to the request
        Console.Write("Resulting Request Headers: ");
        Console.WriteLine(myWebClient.Headers.ToString());


        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(PTC_SERVER);
        // Upload the input string using POST
        byte[] responseArray = myWebClient.UploadData(PTC_SERVER, "POST", byteArray);

        // Upload the file to the URI.
        // The 'UploadFile(uriString,fileName)' method implicitly uses HTTP POST method.
        byte[] fileArray = myWebClient.UploadFile(PTC_SERVER, img);

        // Decode and display the response.
        Console.WriteLine("\nResponse Received.The contents of the file uploaded are:\n{0}",
            System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(fileArray));

        // Decode and display the response.
        Console.WriteLine("\nResponse with IMG received was {0}",
              Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responseArray));

        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for 10 seconds..");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
        Console.WriteLine("End of SendRequest!");
```

Comment: Please explain better what the idea is. Do you want to make multiple requests or just one? In the code you are trying to upload to 2 different servers? Are PTC_SERVER or SERVER the addresses of these different webservers?

Comment: @sigge sorry, SERVER is PTC_SERVER. I'll edit that. I'm trying to make just 1 request